# iScroll - property undefined error

Tags: iscroll4

I'm trying to add 2 instances of iScroll on one page yet I don't think that is the cause of this:

```
function loaded() {

    $('.iScrolls').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $id = $this.attr('id');
        if( $id ) {
            $scrollers[$id] = new iScroll( $id, {
                snap: true,
                momentum: false,
                hScrollbar: false,
                onScrollEnd: function () {
                    $('#indicator > li.active').removeAttr('class');
                    $('#indicator > li:nth-child(' + ( this.currPageX + 1) + ')').removeAttr('class').addClass('active');
                }                              
            });
            $('.prev', $this).click(function(){
                $scrollers[$id].scrollToPage('prev', 0);
                return false;            
            });
            $('.next', $this).click(function(){
                $scrollers[$id].scrollToPage('next', 0);
                return false;                
            });
        }
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

when the "scrollToPage is triggered I get the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

`iScroll.scrollTo iScroll.js:984`

`iScroll._end iScroll.js:614`

`iScroll.handleEvent`

My question being has anyone come across this before and know what causes it?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Was trying to initialise within a hidden container... thats a no no... cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this. Ended up being a silly error as I was passing jQuery style "#wrapperID" instead of just the element id "wrapperID"

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

.iScrolls is your div class name. Can you create an id on that div?

Example:

```
<div class="iScrolls" id="iScrolls">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="thelist">
                // Body part
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```